# using win32com.shell (python) copying of iphone files

Tags: python, iphone, win32com

I am looking to automate copying of files (photos) from iphone.
I got a head start with this python script from github
[list-photos-on-phone](https://github.com/dblume/list-photos-on-phone/blob/master/list-photos-on-phone.py)

I got it to work and get the **file names** of the pictures in iphone

Then I am stuck with just getting the details.I tried looking up the documentation of win32com.shell and item.BindToHandler. It did not help much.

I am using iphone connected to windows 7 by USB and want to copy files. If  it works, then I can do a lot more with this.

Is there a way to *win32com.shell* or some other windows package (in python) to copy the files?